# For time-critical C# code, should I value static methods in my struct (over non-static ones)?

Tags: c#, optimization, compilation

From some researching, I know the static method below can get JIT inlined. But can the non-static ones get inlined as well?

If the code is really time-critical, should I bother valuing this kind of static methods over non-static ones?

```
public struct PixelData
{
    public readonly uint raw;

    public PixelData(uint raw)
    {
        this.raw = raw;
    }

    //JIT inlines this
    static bool HasLineOfSight(PixelData p)
    {
        return (p.raw & 0x8000) != 0;
    }

    //But what about this?
    int GetWeight()
    {
        return (int)(raw & 0x3FFF);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't try to be smarter than a compiler. If you have a time-critical code, measure. You should try different approaches and benchmark them against each other.

Comment: @xanatos true, but now the *static* method has an explicit parameter of PixelData, which might very well be called `@this`. This is a micro-optimization and I wouldn't bother thinking about it until the program is running and you experience a performance problem that could be realiably traced back to the `PixelData`.

Comment: @Spo1ler I agree too. But just a word of caution. Depending on the nature of the app, you sometimes may not want to wait til the end for optimization because these problems may lead to architectural/design changes. Sometimes it's okay to pre-optimize core code. @ Dirk Agreed

Comment: using struct for time critical computations is a very bad idea. It sounds counter-intuitive but from my experience that is true. just measure it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to the method to try and force inlining:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
int GetWeight()
{
    return (int)(raw & 0x3FFF);
}
```

However, from [this programmer.se answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264390/101945) you can see that inlining vs. not actually makes very little difference:

> Results
>
> ```
> struct get property                               : 0.3097832 seconds
> struct inline get property                        : 0.3079076 seconds
> struct method call with params                    : 1.0925033 seconds
> struct inline method call with params             : 1.0930666 seconds
> struct method call without params                 : 1.5211852 seconds
> struct intline method call without params         : 1.2235001 seconds
> ```

You're best letting the compiler do its thing until you find that you're seeing some real *measurable* performance issues.

Comment: This is very useful as I am micro-optimizing a software-based float implementation. Playing around with params actually led me to noticeable performance gain (5~20%). Also it shows that inlining doesn't really make much difference in benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN: [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> A call to a static method generates a call instruction in Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), whereas a call to an instance method generates a callvirt instruction, which also checks for a null object references. However, most of the time the performance difference between the two is not significant.

Comment: While this is true it only applies to classes, not to structs. A struct instance method is called using a `call`, not a `callvirt`.